# How to generate animation in C/C++

Tags: c, animation, png, gif, giflib

What is a high-level approach to generating for encoding a series of RGB buffers (from e.g. png files) into an animated gif?

I have been studying [giflib](http://giflib.sourceforge.net/) but it seems overly complex. It is very low-level and documentation is sparse, especially on the animation encoder. If I understand correctly, Giflib only manipulates the GIF format; you still need to manually calculate a color mapping, allocate the buffers, etc.

Are there any alternative methods or perhaps more high-level C/C++ libraries that make it easier to encode a few rgb buffers into an animated gif? It seems to me this is a feature that one could expect from a gif toolkit?